# SparkSQL how to add and subtract from time field

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have sparkSQl csreipdt . with data frame  which . cateates besed on SQL select

```
val df_t =   sparkSession.sqlContext.sql(" select datetime from table")
```

I need to return same datetime as **datetime+ 1 minute** and **datetime - 1 minute** I cant find solution on how to do it? Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could you use interval ?

```
spark.sql("""SELECT current_timestamp() - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE, current_timestamp() + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE""").show(false)
```

Answer (score 1):

There could be a more clever way to do it, but once you are pulling the value locally into df_t, seems you could run a lamba on that to increase them all and then commit it back.

Comment: I am very new to SparkSQl and be honest don't understand what are you talking about. I am thinking  to do some thing  like `unix_timestamp('2018-08-12 21:16:32')+60`  bit not sure if it  will work

Comment: Right, what I am saying is, if you are going through the trouble of pulling down a set of values, you don't have to use spark to update them, you can update them and commit them back yourself.

Comment: i will use this dates in where clause to find records I need

Answer (score 0):

Tomasz Krol's answer is perfectly valid.  Here is the same approach with a slightly different syntax:

```
df_t
  .withColumn("datetime_minus_one", 'datetime - expr("INTERVAL 1 minutes"))
  .withColumn("datetime_plus_one", 'datetime + expr("INTERVAL 1 minutes"))
```